# UpdateOrCreate Model Object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using `Laravel 5.5` and I am declaring my model object the following:

```
        $product = new product();
        $product->name = $coinArr[$key];
        $product->symbol = $symbolArr[$key];
        $product->current_price = $priceArr[$key];

        ///save image to public folder
        $fileName = basename($imgArr[$key]);
        Image::make($imgArr[$key])->save(public_path('images/' . $fileName));           
        $product->asset_logo = $fileName;
        //$product->updateOrCreate();
        App/Product::updateOrCreate($product);
```

If the `product` does not exist in the database I would like to create it else just update it.

I tried the following two ways to use the `updateOrCreate` method. However, I receive the following error for `App/Product::updateOrCreate($product);`:

```
  Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::updateOrCreate(), 0 passed in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Coding Projects\laravel_proj\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php on line 1455 and at least 1 expected
```

And the following error for `$product->updateOrCreate();`:

```
Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::updateOrCreate()
```

Any suggestions how to use `updateOrCreate` with my model object?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#other-creation-methods  ... what 2 ways did you try?

Comment: @lagbox Thx for the link. However, the example does not describe how to use my model object with `updateOrCreate ` method. For `save()` I am using the following `product->save()`.

Comment: Make `$product` an array instead of a model instance, and assign it array keys instead of properties, ie, `$product=[]; $product['name']=$coinArr[$key];//etc` and then give that to `updateOrCreate`

Comment: it takes arrays, and 2 arguments, did you try how the docs show to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use updateOrCreate, you need to choose which attributes are used to determine if the product exists already.  The function takes 2 arrays:

```
product::updateOrCreate([
  'name' => $coinArr[$key]  //Laravel will check if this model exists by name
],[
  'symbol' => $symbolArr[$key]  //if exists, will update symbol.  if doesnt exist, will create new with this name and symbol
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how the `updateOrCreate()` method works. In the first parameter you put an array with search conditions. If you want to search existing route by name for example, the correct syntax will be:

```
Product::updateOrCreate(
    [
         'name' => $coinArr[$key]
    ],
    [
        'symbol' => $symbolArr[$key],
        'current_price' => $symbolArr[$key],
        'asset_logo' => $fileName
    ]
);
```

The second parameter is array for creating a new object.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#other-creation-methods